# Safari bad frames rendering

Tags: safari, frame

I've finished a site but it doesn't work well on Safari.
I used (don't blame me!) frames and two white weird spaces appeared on the left ant the right of the frame "body"

you can se the result here:
http://www.yves-ratheau.com/

I didn't find any help on google, forums, etc...

thanks to any suggestion

Comment: Looks fine to me... what version of Safari are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm installing windows on my main Mac, I grabbed a really old laptop (Powerbook g3/safari4.04 on OS X 10.4.11) to test this and didn't get any white lines anywhere. What safari version are you using to test?

You may need to set some CSS padding/margin/border styles to "none" to have it work in older versions of Safari, but I've never seen this problem before.